# How to save date which has already ID from different table

Tags: laravel

I have a table call order I want to store but I made my relation with the customer table because I need the `customer_id` but now I get this error:

> customers_id doesn't have a default value

This is the relation in my `Order` model:

```
public function customer()

{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer_id', 'id');
}
```

`Customer` model:

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'customers_id');
}
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $orderDate = $request->only(['shippingAddress', 'receivingAddress','status']);
    $order = Order::create($orderDate);

    return redirect()->route('order.index',compact('order'));
}
```

What's wrong with the above code ?

Answer (score 0):

What does this mean default value of customer_id ?

In this case: I see you don't have `customer_id` in order to create an order.

If customer login and make an order you can use it to specify customer_id

`$orderDate['customer_id'] = Auth::user()->id;`

Answer (score 0):

The error is because when you are saving the order the `customers_id` column is null. If you haven't marked the column as nullable and do not pass a value when inserting a new record DBMS will complain that the column does not have a default value.

You have to set the customer before saving the order.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $orderDate = $request->only(['shippingAddress', 'receivingAddress','status']);

    // Get the customer
    $customer = $request->user();

    $orderDate['customer_id'] = $customer->id
    $order = Order::create($orderDate);
    // or
    // Using the relation
    // $order = $customer->orders()->save(new Order($orderDate));

    return redirect()->route('order.index',compact('order'));
}
```